# How to unmount an Azure File Share

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've got a Windows Server VM on Azure. I also have a File Share. According to the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files), one can mount the drive using the following command:

```
net use <drive-letter>: \\<storage-account-name>.file.core.windows.net\<share-name>
```

This does indeed work.

Unfortunately, the documentation makes no mention of how to unmount the storage...

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To unmount a `File Share` drive, simply use:

```
net use <drive-letter> /delete
```

This will detach the drive.

Comment: Great. Thank you! It would be nice if we could use /detach rather than /delete. Delete sounds scary, like all disk contents will be removed...

Comment: `Delete` actually detaches it. But I agree that it does sound scary. BTW, I have updated the documentation to include these instructions there. Submitted a Pull Request. Hopefully it will get approved :).

Comment: This works. I have to add that you need to do it as an Administrator, otherwise it just hangs (in my case). And reboot Windows, otherwise Explorer was acting weird.

Answer (score 2):

I found this looking for an answer for a Linux VM.  Since the question title may lead others here too, I'll add a Linux solution:

`sudo umount /mnt/<yourfileshare>` #sudo is required

This assumes that your Azure FileShare was mounted at `/mnt/<yourfileshare>`, which is what the pre-built script does.

Answer (score 1):

> how to unmount the storage

You can login your VM via RDP, then select network locations and select the file share disk. select **disconnect**.
[image]

Comment: If you don't want to use this file share any more, we may delete the file share via azure portal.